# Sphere Material: 360-Video From Ultra-Fisheye Lens

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, 3d-modelling, 3d-texture

For about a year I've been successfully creating 360-videosphere VR experiences in Unity, using Unity's MovieTexture and ultra-wide panoramic mp4 videos. Stitched together from five GoPro cameras, the source videos were 1200x800 wide, with the stitched-together video imagery comprising the center and black bands at the top and foot of video image. Applied as a MovieTexture to the inside of a standard sphere (with normals reversed) this produced a more than acceptable video-sphere experience, with no distortion to the video image as the wide pano wrapped perfectly around the inside of the sphere.

Now, I am trying to use source video from a single-lens camera called a 360-Fly. The 360-Fly captures a 240 degree field-of-videw and produces a perfectly square and highly distorted fisheye video. The fisheye video is at the center of the square format, with black at the four corners of the frame. The very center of the video image is the space directly above the camera, and the edges of the frame is the 360-degree horizon around the camera.

I'm still a complete n00b regarding materials, textures, and how exactly they get applied (wrapped) around meshes. Applying the square format fisheye video to a sphere creates a highly distorted image. I'm assuming I need to apply this MovieTexture to something other than a perfect sphere.

How would I apply this square-format fisheye MovieTexture to a sphere in order to compensate for the fisheye distortion? What type of sphere or half-dome or oblate spheroid should I create? Is there some other change to the manner in which the material needs to be applied?

Comment: You still need a perfect sphere - but you have to change the UV map to match your projection.